# Would like to concatenate (vstack) 3 dataframes, but when I try it is returning the 3 different dataframes one under another instead of concatenating

Tags: python, pandas

Below is the code that I have tried and the image is the output when I try running this.

There are 3 csv's I am loading with the index column name key

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
import glob 
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()
directory = './csvdir'
output_filename = "output.csv"

def combine_csv_files(directory, output_filename):
    for f in Path(directory).glob("*.csv"): 
        
        try: 
            df = pd.read_csv(f, index_col="key")  
            concat1 = pd.concat([df], axis=0)
            print(concat1)
        except ValueError as e: 
            print(f"{f.name} does not have a key column")
            
combine_csv_files(directory, output_filename)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't `concat` the new data to the old one.
Try this :

```
def combine_csv_files(directory, output_filename):
    for i, f in enumerate(Path(directory).glob("*.csv")): 
        
        try: 
            df = pd.read_csv(f, index_col="key")
            if i == 0 :
                concat1 = df
            else :
                concat1 = pd.concat([concat1, df], axis = 0)
            print(concat1)
        except ValueError as e: 
            print(f"{f.name} does not have a key column")
            
combine_csv_files(directory, output_filename)
```

Comment: @LucasBlatchford Will be appreciate if you accept the answer.

Comment: @DennyChen What about the case when you raise a ValueError on the first csv file? You would be later concatenating with an undefined concat1.

Comment: Also you could be doing many concatenations when a single one is needed, and these can be a costly operation

Comment: @Learningisamess what about import the data first and try set_index except continue

Comment: @Learningisamess I saw your answer, I think it is better since it is more prudent.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is printing the dataframe, one at the time, instead of concatenating them. Try:

```py
def combine_csv_files(directory, output_filename):

    dfs = []
    for f in Path(directory).glob("*.csv"): 
        
        try: 
            df = pd.read_csv(f, index_col="key")  
            dfs.append(df)
        except ValueError as e: 
            print(f"{f.name} does not have a key column")
    return pd.concat(dfs)
            
combine_csv_files(directory, output_filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first define a container outside of the loop and then use `np.append` or `pd.concat` method. You can also use `pd.merge` method, but note that if you don't define a global variable(i.e., out of the loop), your stored data will be lost after each iteration.

Comment: Please add some code examples to your answers. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.